# Getting "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" for my code

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Here is my code in python for which I am getting TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
     s = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
     return s

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    s = sigmoid(x)
    ds = s(1-s)
    return ds


x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print ("sigmoid_derivative(x) = " + str(sigmoid_derivative(x)))
```

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Good to see the error-code is working. What's the question?

Comment: It should be `s*(1-s)`  not `s(1-s)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It worked.