# Pyomo, TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, pyomo

I am trying to use scipy commands in [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/), an optimizer based in Python.

My goal is to develop an optimal trajectory for aircraft in the presence of a wind field. I have data measurements at grid points. I have used scipy to generate the interpolation as

```
xi, yi = np.linspace(X2.astype('float').min(), X2.astype('float').max(), 100), np.linspace(Y2.astype('float').min(), Y2.astype('float').max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# Interpolate
rbfX = sp.interpolate.Rbf(X2, Y2, Wx2, function='multiquadric')
zXi = rbfX(xi, yi)
```

being sp how I call scipy. This is the way I have to calculate the speed of wind at any point. I am interpolating the windspeed.

Then, inside of the pyomo part, I write

```
def Wind_lammda_definition1(model, i):
    return m.Wind_lammda[i,1] ==zXi(m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1])
m.Wind_lammda_const1 = Constraint(m.N, rule = Wind_lammda_definition1)
```

being m.lammda and m.phi the position of the airplane.

Unfortunately, once I run the code, I get rhe following error:

```
    return m.Wind_lammda[i,1] ==zXi(m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1])

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003423/getting-typeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-is-not-callable-for-my-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263043/numpy-ndarray-object-is-not-callable) threads and as far as I see, this is an error message which appears if there are syntax errors. However, I haven't found any and I think that this happens becasue I cannot port scipy into Pyomo. Is this true or can it be fixed?

Comment: What is `zXi`?  A function is called with `func(args)` syntax.  An array is indexed with `arr[...]`.  You've shown us unrelated pieces of code, so we can't decipher what the various variables are.  But the key point here is that you are using array object as though it were a function, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: `zXi` is at the end of the first code, `zXi = rbfX(xi, yi)`. My idea is to calculate the value of the wind at each point defined by the X and Y coordinates in which the airplane is, `m.lammda[i,1]` and `m.phi[i,1]`. I am using the pseudospectral radau method with  step of 50, so I have 51 points in which the function will be evaluated, represented by `i`. The second index represent the number of aircraft, since I am working in conflict detection. I need the value of the windspeed in each of the 50 positions. I hope I have explained myself.Feel free to ask if I haven't managed to explain myself

Comment: In the function `Wind_lammda_definition1`, you use the expression `zXi(m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1])`.  That is the source of the error.  `zXi` is a NumPy array; you can't call a NumPy array like that.

Comment: Why are you using `zXi(m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1])` instead of `zXi[m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1]]`.  In Python `()` is different from `[]`.  One is for function calls, the other for indexing.

Comment: @WarrrenWeckesser. So, what I want is impossible or is there a way to call zXi from the inside of the pyomo code? Also, @hpaulj, if I change the parenthesis to brackets, I get the error`return m.Wind_lammda[i,1] ==zXi[m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1]]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: You don't seem to have grasped that `zXi` is not something you can **call**.  I showed how it can be **indexed**, but apparently the things you are using as arguments/indexes are not valid indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's setup a `Rbf` object:

```
In [177]: X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(4),np.arange(4))
In [178]: Z = np.sin(X-Y)
In [179]: fn = interpolate.Rbf(X,Y,Z)
In [180]: type(fn)
Out[180]: scipy.interpolate.rbf.Rbf
```

That's like your `rbfX`.  According to the docs it is `callable`, that is it has a `__call__` method.

If we call it with 2 scalars, we get a single element array:

```
In [181]: fn(1.5, 2.3)
Out[181]: array(-0.73094599)
```

Call it with a pair of arrays, we get an array with matching size:

```
In [184]: fn(np.arange(1,3,.5), np.arange(0,2,.5))
Out[184]: array([0.84147098, 0.85639014, 0.84147098, 0.85639014])
```

This is what your `zXi`.  Look at its `type`, `shape`, and `dtype`.  It's an array.  It cannot be "called", and there are specific rules as to how it can be indexed.

`zXi(m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1])` is wrong because it tries to "call" a numpy array.  But `zXi[m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1]]` apparently has invalid indices, quite possibly floats.  I haven't examined what they are.

`rbfX(m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1])` might work if the 2 arguments are meant to be interpolation points.

`zXi = rbfX(xi, yi)` creates an array (probably 2d (100,100)) that contains values interpolated at the `xi,yi` mesh.  You can pick an element, e.g `zXi[50,50]` or array of values.  But you can't treat it like the interpolation function, giving it float values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see what is happening. I have changed my code so that it looks like `return m.Wind_lammda[i,1] ==rbfX(m.lammda[i,1], m.phi[i,1])`. Unfortunately, it returns now `
  File "pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx", line 588, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.NumericValue.__float__

TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `lammda[0,1]' to a float is
disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as
arguments to one of the Python built-in math module functions when
defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math
functions.`

Comment: I don't think there is a solution to this. Right?

Comment: I don't know anything about `pyomo..  `rbfX` expects 2 floats, or float dtype arrays.

Comment: I am not a programmer either. I have checked the documentation of pyomo (https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/) and I only see in the word interpolation in pages 339 and 340. I am not proficient enough to understand what is going on.