# Can I convert pyomo internal variable to float

Tags: python, variables, interpolation, document, pyomo

I have defined an interpolation function in Python as:

```
rbfX = sp.interpolate.Rbf(X2, Y2, Wx2, function='multiquadric')
```

I want to use it inside of a Pyomo code, where `m.lammda[i,1]` and `m.phi[i,1]` are the positions of an airplane moving inside of a wind field represented by the previous interpolation. Note that `m` is a concrete model and

```
type(m.lammda)
Out[7]: pyomo.core.base.var.IndexedVar
```

My current attempt at a solution is

```
def Wind_lammda_definition1(model, i):
   abcdX=float(m.lammda[i,1])
   abcdY=float(m.phi[i,1])
   return m.Wind_lammda[i,1] ==rbfX(abcdX, abcdY)
m.Wind_lammda_const1 = Constraint(m.N, rule = Wind_lammda_definition1)
```

Since I want to know the windspeed at any point in the trajectory.

When I run the program, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint
    Wind_lammda_const1 with index 0: TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo
    NumericValue type `lammda[0,1]' to a float is disabled. This error is
    often the result of using Pyomo components as arguments to one of the
    Python built-in math module functions when defining expressions. Avoid
    this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions.
ERROR: Constructing component 'Wind_lammda_const1' from data=None failed:
    TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `lammda[0,1]' to
    a float is disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo
    components as arguments to one of the Python built-in math module
    functions when defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-
    provided math functions.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\whatever\node1_test.py", line 530, in <module>
    m.Wind_lammda_const1 = Constraint(m.N, rule = Wind_lammda_definition1)

TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `lammda[0,1]' to a float is
disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as
arguments to one of the Python built-in math module functions when
defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math
functions.
```

The error still appears if I call `m.lammda[i,1]` and `m.phi[i,1]` as arguments instead of `abcdX` and `abcY`.

I need to know if I can somehow adapt this code to work. I have read the [documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/). In pages 339 to 340 it talks about interpolation, but I am not familiar enough with Pyomo nor Python to understand it, so please, I would be extremely thankful if someone aided me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of info from this and you another threads. I will try to handle all as I can.

The problem is not converting `pyomo.IndexedVar` to `float`, since when you create the variable in the `pyomo` model you can do it as a `NonNegativeReal`. This problem is rather the implicit convertion of not a number (In your code, `m.lammda[i,1]` is a class, not exactly a number. Even though it has a float value) with the `float` statement.

As you stated [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69543751/pyomo-typeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-is-not-callable#comment122934573_69546461) in another thread, when you try to  use the `pyomo.environ.IndexedVar` into the fitting (interpolation) function Rbf, you raise the `TypeError` of error trying to convert the an `IndexedVar` to `float` (internally in the Rbf function). To evaluate the value you can use `model.m.lammda[i,1]()` since calling the class returns you the value, but this still will not help, because another error will certainly raise

I recommend you to visit [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/pyomo-forum/c/4n8rnycjpTU) to get more information about the potential difficulty of using an external function as a `pyomo` Constraint or Objective Function

`Pyomo` got a [Piecewise Function Library](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/kernel/piecewise/piecewise_nd.html) where you can model a linear (`pyo.environ` layer also got it in the `pyo.environ.Piecewise`) or multilinear interpolation, but you will need to work with the [kernel layer](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/kernel/index.html), it use scipy to generate a Dlunay for the interpolation, you can check using `help(pyomo.kernel.piecewise_nd)`. This surely may work to you, but it requires a little be of work.